# How can I generate a list of the security groups a set of users belong to?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, groups

I have been asked to generate a list of the security groups (so specifically not the distribution groups) that a list of approximately 50 users belong to.

I have a list of users, `users.txt` that contains each username on a new line.  I want to generate a `membership.txt` that contains the username and a list of the security groups that user is a member of, separated by commas.

The Powershell script I have written so far is as follows:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\users.txt

ForEach ($User in $users) {
  $getmembership = Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof
  $User + ',' + $getmembership | Out-File -Append c:\membership.txt
}
```

This almost works, but for two problems:

1. It is generating a list of all groups, not just security groups.  How can I tell it to only include security groups and not distribution groups?
2. The groups are being appended in the format `OU=Security Groups,OU=City,DC=domain,DC=com CN=Senior Leaders`, but the only information I actually want is `Senior Leaders`.  How can I cut out all the extra information?

Comment: Are you also looking to walk their nested group memberships?

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for something that is out there already: http://www.cjwdev.co.uk/Software/ADReportingTool/Info.html

Comment: @jscott No, that will not be necessary.

Comment: @TheCleaner I will try this out and see if it fits the bill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend your `Get-ADUser` line:

```
$getmembership = Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty memberof | Get-ADGroup -Properties name | Where { $_.GroupCategory -eq 'Security' } | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

This will feed the DN of the Group to `Get-ADGroup` to retrieve additional properties, then filter on group category and select the name of the group (instead of the DistinguishedName).

Comment: This appears to return almost no groups...  I see mostly this:

    `username,
    username,
    username,@{Name=Group}
    username,
    username,
    username,@{Name=Different Group}`

Comment: Sorry, missed an `ExpandProperty`, corrected.

Comment: Sorry, the only thing that's not working is comma-separating the groups.  Lots of our groups have spaces in the names so I can't rely on spacing to parse the groups out.  I can't work out the syntax to add a comma between each group.

Comment: Simple: `$User + ',' + ($getmembership -join ',')`