# Powershell - how can i list both username and group membership for users of a named group?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am relatively new to powershell and I have two statements on the cmd line:

`get-adgroupmember <group name> | select-object name,samaccountname`

To produce a nicely formatted table with two columns of a persons real name and their username.

`get-adgroupmember <group name> | get-adprincipalgroupmembership | select-object name`

To produce list of groups that each user in a named group belongs to.

I would like to combine these so that I have a users real name + username and then the groups they belong to for each user
e.g.

```
name                samaccountname          memberof
----                --------------          --------
joe bloggs          jbloggs                 group1
                                            group2
                                            groupq

bob laithwaite      blaithwaite             group2
                                            groupm
                                            groupp
                                            groupq
```

or maybe

```
joe bloggs          jbloggs
group1
group2
groupq

bob laithwaite      blaithwaite
group2
groupm
groupp
groupq
```

Is there any simple way to create this?  I am not overly concerned about it being beautiful.

If there is no simple way can anyone give me any pointers to how I can create this a difficult way?  If there is only a difficult way then whilst a working answer would be nice I would sooner have pointers to start with to see if I can produce something myself.  I am still learning after all.

My original Google search found https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Get-users-who-b0420fe1 but could not get it to work on the cmd line by replacing variables with hard coded strings.  This is  what I ultimately want to achieve but with just 2 groups however in the first instance I want to start with something like the output above.

I also found [How can I generate a list of the security groups a set of users belong to?](https://serverfault.com/questions/631334/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-the-security-groups-a-set-of-users-belong-to) in the process of writing this question but this just appears to produce similar list to that which I created in the 2nd cmd line, the one that uses get-adprincipalgroupmembership.

Comment: Are you still awaiting a correct answer?  ServerFault prides itself on its high answer rate.

Comment: i have not had an opportunity to try anything as of yet as work has been a bit hectic but i am working the weekend which normally gives me more "free" time (don't tell the boss)

Answer (score 0):

There's no single line or single cmdlet that will give you what you want, but with a little scripting you can get it. I've drafted a script below which will do it, it's very simple and you should be able to understand what it's doing and modify it to your needs.

```
ipmo activedirectory

$searchBase = "OU=someOU,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"

$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $searchBase -Properties memberOf

$report = @()

Foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
    $name = $user.Name
    $SAM = $user.SAMAccountName
    $memberOf = $user.memberOf

    $i = 0 #if you only want the user and SAMAccountName to appear once you will need a counter like this, it'se easier to just display it on every row


    Foreach($Group in $memberOf)
    {
        $GroupName = $Group.Replace('CN=','')
        $rowGroup = $GroupName -replace ",.*"

        if($i -eq 0) #if you're happy to have username and SAMAccountName on each row you can skip this bit
        {
            $rowName = $name
            $rowSAM = $SAM
        }
        else
        {
            $rowName = ""
            $rowSAM = ""
        }

        $objRow = New-Object System.Object
        $objRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $rowName
        $objRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SAMAccountName -Value $rowSAM
        $objRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name GroupName -Value $rowGroup

        $report += $objRow

        $i++

    }

}

$report | ft
```

Comment: I'd take a look at `[pscustomobject][ordered]@{}` for building new objects, I think this was introduced in Powershell v3. It's very helpful and gets rid of the `New-Object` ugliness.

Comment: Yeah looks like this is an old answer - I've switched to [PSCustomObject] now. Haven't come across the [ordered] attribute though, will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Yep it's super neat, it orders otherwise un-ordered hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

In your post you didn't specify where your user list is coming from.  It looks like you're getting the users of one group and seeing what else they're a member of.  It's largely irrelevant to the solution so I'll assume you have a list of `$users` and go from there.

What you want to do is combine properties from two commands into a single output stream.  This can be accomplished by leveraging [Calculated Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) like so...

```
$Users | %{Select DisplayName,SamAccountName,@{N="Groups";E={(Get-ADuser $_.SamAccountName -Properties memberof).memberof}}}
```

You could also use an approach similar to this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember $GroupName | %{Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName -Properties memberof | Select Name, SamAccountName, memberof}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way, this will give you list of users with all the groups then are in

```
$users = get-content \\filepath.txt
foreach($u in $users){
  $report += Get-Aduser $u -properties memberof| Get-ADGroup |select-object @{N="GroupName";E={$_.samaccountname}},@{N="username";E={$u}}
}

$report | Export-csv \\filepath.csv
```